# Slim Framework Ajax jQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slim

I have a profile page where a logged on user could send a friend request. This is a (twig) view:

```
{% extends 'templates/default.php' %}

{% block title %}{{ user.getFullNameOrUsername }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>{{ user.username }}</h2>
{% if auth %}
<input type="submit" value="Send Friend Request" id="sfr">
<br>
{% endif %}
<img src="" alt="Profile picture for {{ user.getFullNameOrUsername }}">
<dl>
{% if user.getFullName  %}
    <dt>Full Name</dt>
    <dd>{{ user.getFullName }}</dd>
{% endif %}

<dt>Email</dt>
<dd>{{ user.email }}</dd>
</dl>
{% endblock %}
```

The location of this page is:

http://localhost/authentication/public/u/martin but on the file directory as C:\xampp2\htdocs\authentication\app\views\user\profile.php

Once the user clicks the "Send Friend Request" button, the following js is ran:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


  $("#sfr").click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/authentication/app/routes/account/friend.php",
  data: { fr: "sfr"}
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    console.log(msg);
    alert( msg );
  });

});     

});
```

I created a route called friend and it looks like this:

```
<?php

$app->post('/profile', $authenticated(), function() use ($app) {

    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    $request = $app->request();

    $fr = $request->post('fr');

    echo "Friend Request sent";


})->name('account.friend.post');
```

I get the following error message:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: app in <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\authentication\app\routes\account\friend.php</b> on line    <b>3</b><br />
```

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function post() on null in     <b>C:\xampp2\htdocs\authentication\app\routes\account\friend.php</b> on line   <b>3</b><br />
```

I think the issue is in the url in the ajax call. I wish I could route it to the name of the route and not its location.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You must include the slim framework using
 `require 'path_to_slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling the `friend.php` file rather than calling the route. On the URL in your AJAX code, call the route:
$( document ).ready(function() {

```
$("#sfr").click(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/authentication/app/routes/account/profile",
      data: { fr: "sfr"}
   })
   .done(function( msg ) {
      console.log(msg);
      alert( msg );
   });
});
```

Make sure you have registered the POST route `/profile` in the Slim app instantiation.